# react-native-webview issue with redirect using links, WebView under react-native used to work fine (Expo)

Tags: android, react-native, webview, expo, react-native-webview

I am loading one site in WebView. It is loaded successfully with login page. Once I login, I can perform few operations which are performed using input button -> submit action. However, when I click on any link that redirects to some other page, it is failing with below error.

```
Object {
    "canGoBack": true,
    "canGoForward": false,
    "description": "Not Found",
    "loading": true,
    "statusCode": 404,
    "target": 475,
    "title": "Site Title",
    "url": "https://mysite.doamin.com/mini/Finance;jsessionid=00006ooEx2d9GxujmpZ_O2plRfE:185s9fc4n?bwayparam=rt%2FATVZ97VolfHr%2F404k2mrZbLeia%2BNbS0IeUHfNtaozXwI8pZJE8Jlr%2B6Qc%2B5Yu%2BjCiZDWRTRCMarhpklSVhhIQBmvsr65nTLFzUSoxizdZKRLZt2ZNsUUOQSdrl7PY%0D%0A9kxlcfqEDpTTPiCDoea1KVsuqYg4AJebkCKM87n8C%2FUO9JL5YGDHPwqO5XMtxR%2FREK0wtLuYJ4lBV67dnXXCrwYQOZdVDQyTxK7gMygSBqs%3D",
}
```

Below code works - Expo 35 (when WebView was part of **react-native**):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://mysite.doamin.com' }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Below code does not work - Expo 36 (when WebView was removed from react-native and now part of **react-native-webview**):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://mysite.doamin.com' }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Why react-native-webview is not able to load page with URL given in above error message? Is there a change in WebView when it is now part of react-native-webview?